# Not able to load report through web service using SQL 2005 reporting in coldfusion 10

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, coldfusion

I am getting the error message

"Element cause is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.xml.rpc.ServiceProxy$ServiceInvocationException"

while  calling the LoadReport() to load the report rdl file in ColdFusion 10 through web service.

It is working fine when i am using the SQL 2008 report server but it is giving the above error in SQL 2005 reporting service in client's staging server.

Below is the piece of code where exactly i am facing the issue:

> var webServiceObj =
>   CreateObject("webservice",THIS.GetReportWebServiceURL(),
>                                                  {username=THIS.GetUsername(), password=THIS.GetPassword()});
>
> var execInfo =
>   webServiceObj.loadReport(javacast('string','ReportName'),javacast("nu
>   ll",""),trustedUserHeader);

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also include the code you're using to create `webServiceObj`?

Comment: Yes Adam, find the below code used to create the web service object:                                                           var webServiceObj = CreateObject("webservice",THIS.GetReportWebServiceURL(),
                            {username=THIS.GetUsername(), password=THIS.GetPassword()});

Comment: Put your code in the question mate, not in the comment.  So what happens if you call the web service just on the browser URL, rather than via CFML code?

Comment: In browser url , i am able to access the web service.